# Angular4 & Webpack - 300kb (after optimization) for a simple "hello world" app?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have created a simple *Hello world* app using Angular 4 (4.3.0).

> Angular files :

*— app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myTitle:string;
   constructor() {
    this.myTitle = `Hello world`;
  }
}
```

*— app.component.html*

```
<h1>
 {{myTitle}}
</h1>
```

*— app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> TypeScript file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",

    "module": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "include": [

      "./**/*"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  } ,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

> Webpack file

[*Here is the full file*](http://jsbin.com/fezoba/edit?html,output) but the important parts are :

```
  config.module.rules.push(
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] }
    );
```

And

```
 if (envOptions.MODE === 'prod') {

    config.module.rules.push(
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] }
    );

    config.plugins = [
      new AotPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
        entryModule: __dirname + '/src/app/app.module#AppModule'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: false,
        beautify: false,
        mangle: {
          screw_ie8: true,
          keep_fnames: true
        },
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
          screw_ie8: true
        },
        comments: false
      }),
    ];
  }
```

> Diagnostics

**Before** optimization - When I run `>webpack` (without `webpack  --env.MODE=prod`)  in cmd , I get this :

[image] ,

Now let's see that the compiler DOES exist:

[image]

Ok now let's run `>webpack  --env.MODE=prod`  , and I do see smaller files :

[image]

Also - source explorer DOES show that compiler is gone :

[image]

**Question**

Is that the minimum size I can get for an *Hello world* app ? I read that uglifyjs also does tree shaking.
How can I minimize the output files ? **250K still looks huge** for such a simple task.

### update

Adding GZIP plugin  , using this configuration :

```
new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
     algorithm: "gzip",
     test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
     threshold: 10240,
     minRatio: 0.8
 })
```

[image]

The size is 60K app + 20K polyfill  = 80k apprx.

But I've read that a simple *hello world* should take about 20k so ? ?

Comment: did you try `AOT` ?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of modern web development!

Comment: @Dhyey did you read the code where it's written `new AotPlugin`  ? :-)

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins What makes you think i'm new to this world  :-)? if I were new  , I would've accept it as a fact. But there's something I'm missing (obviously ,I hope not).

Comment: @RoyiNamir Did you use `angular-cli` to create your project ?

Comment: I can see from your profile you are not new. It was a stab at the absurdities  involved in the software bloat in modern frameworks that require you to `gulp` and `bower` and `lint` and `aot` and `bundle` and `polyfill` and ... etc.. all of these massive packages filled with code that you are probably never going to use.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I've created it via CLi initially. then I've removed all unnecessary parts ( I know what is unnecessary). My package json and wepack contains the minimum modules and all optimizations plugins, as you can see in the linked files in my question

Comment: @RoyiNamir sorry i did not see the `new AotPlugin` code. With the `angular` framework and `zonejs` 250k seems ok. Did u try serving **gzipped** files which will further reduce the size ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Ok. The result with `angular-cli` and the unnecessary parts was hugier than your optimizations ? My guess is the same as @AlexanderHiggins : even for a simple app you have tons of libraries that makes your app heavy.

Comment: @Dhyey I don't think it's a matter of `serving files` but of `why a simple app is huge like that`. `Hello World` apps are known for their simplicity are "we"  expect a small (in size) app as a result (which is not the case here).

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ i was trying to address the last line `How can I minimize the output files ?` of OP.

Comment: That's pretty much ok, it was 700kb not so long ago. It will look even less threatening when being gzipped (that's how all library devs sweeten the stats). I believe the devs improved the numbers with Closure compiler. Nobody uses the framework for Hello World, so all the fuss is pretty much pointless.

Comment: @estus I disagree. The application will only get larger when you add more features. 250kB as a baseline is just too much. I've built a whole price comparison application with Vue.js in 220kB of JavaScript (without Gzip).

Comment: @str Angular itself is a relatively small part of real-world app's footprint where usage of the framework can be really justified. The ones who care about framework footprint too much can go Vue, AngularJS or else, with all their pros and cons. 3 years ago I would call Vue a big fat hog, because A1 was <100kb at that time.

Comment: @Dhyey please read my update.

Comment: can u pls tell us where did u read the 20KB thing ?

Comment: @Dhyey “Angular Router: Declarative Lazy Loading” https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee    read the first paragraph. It's Victor he knows what he talks about

Comment: @RoyiNamir I seriously do not have any idea how to get it even near 20k as only polyfill takes 20k. Maybe try sending Victor a crate of bears chilled with ice from antarctica, maybe then he will tell u the secret :)

Comment: @Dhyey The secret : `console.log('Hello world')`

Comment: @RoyiNamir `One of the techniques we use extensively is dead code elimination` (c) Victor.  I am sure he is talking about `closure compiler` that they are using internally at google. You can run `webpack bundle analyzer` and see what exactly sits in the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking at it wrong. **If you need a simple HelloWorld application you shouldn't be using a framework at all.**
UI frameworks do all kinds of "magic" to enable reuse of components & code, manage your state (Redux for example) ... etc. Thus, around 200KB initial loading of a large application seems reasonable. If you want to cut down the initial load, check what's called "progressive loading" - it can be achieved with the help of Webpack plugins.
Further reading:
https://blog.lavrton.com/progressive-loading-for-modern-web-applications-via-code-splitting-fb43999735c6
https://medium.com/@addyosmani/progressive-web-apps-with-react-js-part-2-page-load-performance-33b932d97cf2

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the size of your node_modules folder? This could contain some stuff you don't need.

Also, be sure to check out this link: http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/.

In this lik they explain how you can achieve a smaller sized app (55kb for HelloWorld).

Hope this helps!